# Nuxt SSR without client call

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

Hello i want to know if i can renderize a `.vue` component into a only server side variable. Usually nuxt renderize html code after a client call. It generate html code on the server side and send it to the client. In my case i need to do the same thing but, the code should be sent into my same server. My idea is to make a direct call to the internal Nuxt renderize function. I would do this call from my server webhook.

so i would do something like that (pseudocode)

```
//my-server-webhook.ts

const html = await getRenderedComponent('/path/to/component.vue')
```

i just wonder if nuxt allow to do something like this on a easy way. thank you in advance.

Comment: If the server is the same, he can generate it on its own.

Comment: how? yeah it's the same

Comment: "Usually nuxt renderize html code after a client call", not really or I'm not sure what you mean here. The initial render is done on the server but then you have a hydration phase + SPA pretty much. Why don't you start on the server directly? Server routes maybe?

Comment: i meant that it generate code on the server then send the first html to the client. But how can a server route renderize a vue component?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by "renderizing a component" exactly?

Comment: i want to turn it into a jpeg. but all should happen on server side

Comment: Turn a `.vue` file into a `.jpg`? What do you mean exactly? Still not clear.

Comment: yeah. but for first i have to turn it into a plain html

Comment: So, `.vue` -> `.html` -> `.jpg`? Even more unclear. Please describe what you want to achieve rather than intermediary steps. It's a XY problem here, we're both not making any progress.

Comment: yeah. but my question is mainly about the .vue -> .html part. i need to extract all plain html from a .vue component and put it into a variable (server side)

Comment: Good luck with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem.

```
npm i puppeteer
```

puppeteer is a headless browser that can be used into nodejs servers. Now i can renderize html pages and turn them into images all from my server.